# Using a different major mode in comments

Tags: major-mode, comment, literate-programming

A programming language that I use lets me format comments and docstrings using markdown, and then export my code and documentation to PDF.

When I edit the file, though, Emacs doesn't see comments as markdown; just as plain boring text.

I would like to access the full power of `markdown-mode` when I edit comments, without giving up the nice features of my programming languages' major mode outside of comments. How can I do this?

(A similar problem would include using a Javadoc specific mode map and syntax highlighting inside of Javadoc comments, for example)

Comment: I'm open to better tagging; `mmm-mode` doesn't seem to exist

Answer (score 5):

You can use [poporg](https://github.com/QBobWatson/poporg) for this.
People mostly use it to edit comments in Org mode, but you can use whatever
mode you want by setting `poporg-edit-hook`.

```
(remove-hook 'poporg-edit-hook 'org-mode)
(add-hook 'poporg-edit-hook 'markdown-mode)
```